# Comparison of LoadRunner and SoapUI custom web requests

Tags: soapui, loadrunner

I have a question regarding LoadRunner and SoapUI.I am sending Jason requests to a certain end point using SoapUI and it gets successful response.But, when using LoadRunner 12 for the same, I get authorisation failed error (401). In LoadRunner, I have set utf-8 encoding, enabled winnet replay, even included web_set_user and web_set_sockets_option as well. Does anybody have clue on this??

Comment: You can also use load test from soapui, have you tried?

Comment: Have you queried Google related to Loadrunner web and 401?  There are quite a few great references available.

Comment: Hi, I have googled and found related resources.But, no one of those were helpful to address the mentioned issue. I was just thinking whether it may be a limitation in LoadRunner.

Comment: No, there is a solution on the first page of Google results involving HTTP 401 and LoadRunner.  This is not a limitation of LoadRunner

Answer (score 0):

Your SOAPUI is including a header that your LoadRunner script is not including by default.  Setup a proxy recording session in LoadRunner.   Record your SOAPUI session, passed through the LoadRunner recording proxy.   When the code is generated be sure to generate all headers.

The above combined with publicly available references involving LoadRunner, 401 and headers should provide a path to a resolution.

Answer (score 0):

Please check **headers** in the SoapUI request and response section and add it in script.